# Using Photoshop Organizer with Amazon Prime Photos

Tags: photoshop, file-management, storage

I’ve read Amazon’s Prime Photo service advertised as an unlimited photo storage service. They allow you to save RAW files, which addresses the shortfall of many other online storage services.

**Has anyone been able to link this up to Photoshop Organizer?**

Organizer can currently use an internal or external memory to load a photo catalog before proceeding to Adobe RAW Converter (ACR). If Amazon Prime Photo can be selected as an external/cloud source, this would be a huge unlock for anyone who constantly runs out of space.